# Specifying initial conditions for a PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I have simple diffusion equation with point source at `c(0, t) = 1` and initial condition `c(elsewhere, 0) = 0`. How should I apply `DSolve` or `NDSolve` to solve the equation ? I have tried specifying my initial conditions like this:

```
ic = {c[x > 0, 0] == 0, c[x < 0, 0] == 0, c[0, t] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][c][1, t] == 0}
```

but it fails. Any suggestions?

```
Diff = D[c[x, t], t] - D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0;
ic = {c[x > 0, 0] == 0, c[x < 0, 0] == 0, c[0, t] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][c][1,t] == 0};
s1 = NDSolve[{Diff, ic}, {c[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
Plot3D[c[x, t] /. s1, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Have a look at `DSolve` and `NDSOlve`. There are many examples in the documentation.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your input?

Comment: Ofcourse,

Diff = D[c[x, t], t] -  D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0;
ic = {c[x > 0, 0] == 0, c[x < 0, 0] == 0, c[0, t] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][c][1, t] == 0};
s1 = NDSolve[{Diff, ic}, {c[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];

Plot3D[c[x, t] /. s1, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
any advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax `c[x > 0, 0]` is not valid, try this:

```
 Diff = D[c[x, t], t] - D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0;
 ic = {c[x, 0] == If[x != 0, 0, 1], c[0, t] == 1, 
      Derivative[1, 0][c][1, t] == 0};
 s1 = NDSolve[{Diff, ic}, {c[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

You get a solution, however note that B.C. is ill conditioned  in that the soluion must go sharply from zero to 1 right at the corner.

```
 Plot3D[c[x, t] /. s1, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

If you look at the solution along t=0 you see it struggling to satisfy the incompatible conditions:

[image]